# How do you return a zero if there is nothing in the grid where you checked?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

To start things off, I am making a game. You fight on a 3x3 Grid (using a 2 Dimensional-Array), and if the "Lane#" (Lane# = Row + Col) ahead of you is blank then you get a -15% Damage Reduction, and this stacks for every blank lane.

This means if you are on [0][0] then you are in Lane# 0, and therefore, cannot possibly have anyone ahead of you, and you will always take 100% of Damage (this is of course without defense and yadda yadda else that modifies)

And if you are on [2][2] then you are in Lane# 4, and if every lane ahead of you has atleast one space in it taken, then you will take 15*4 = 60, 100-60 = 40% of actual damage.

Now that that is out of the way. I am having difficulty returning 0... I keep getting an Error that says that you cannot return a Void value...

'cannot return a value from method whose result type is void'

```
public Blanks(int l) { //l = Lane
    int x = 0; //The Return
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) //The loop
        if (l=0){ //Here I keep getting an error saying 'incompatible types'
            x = 0;
            return x; //Here is the 'cannot return a void value' error
            break;
        }
        if (l>=1){
            x++;
        }
        if (l>=2){
            x++;
        }
        if (l>=3){
            x++;
        }
        if (l>=4){
            x++;
        }
        return x; //for some odd reason, this is also a void value
    }
}
```

I still have yet to add the Checking the Array / Grid part as I am stumped about that one as well.. but another problem, another question.. the actual array itself..

Comment: use double equal sign for equality check `==`. The single equal sign `=` is for assignment. Also, your `Blanks` class does not have any return type. Thus you cannot `return` something. Change it to `public int Blanks(int l)` note the inserted `int` keyword there.

Comment: Thanks! That was a very fast answer!

Comment: Ah yes, it is probably better to call it *comment* which answers the question - or *comment answering question(?)*...

Answer (score 0):

In order to return an integer value you have to mention a return type in the method. Also, in the first if statement you have used assignment operator instead of comparing.

Also why you have used break after return. I think you have to do first break and then return in the end.

One more thing to add. Your for loop should contain braces. Only the first if statement will get executed according to your code.

```
public int Blanks(int l) { //l = Lane
    int x = 0; //The Return
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) //The loop
        if (l==0){ //Here I keep getting an error saying 'incompatible types'
            x = 0;
            break;
        }
        if (l>=1){
            x++;
        }
        if (l>=2){
            x++;
        }
        if (l>=3){
            x++;
        }
        if (l>=4){
            x++;
        }
        return x; //for some odd reason, this is also a void value
    }
}
```

I haven't stepped into your logic. Comment if you face any problem after this.

Comment: Okay.. I tried your fixes as well... but then I realized something.. If I make my loop 'i < 6' then does that mean that this checks the Array 6 times? or it goes through the 6 steps?

Answer (score 0):

you should modify the method header to `public int Blanks(int l) {` 
and you should remove `break;` keyword because you return method value before it and will be unreached statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using the for loop here, but this is a way to do it:

```
public int Blanks(int l) { 
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        if (l==0){
            x = 0;
        }else {
            x++;
        }
    return x; 
}
```

But in case that `l==0` your method will return 5;

If you want to return `0` or `1` then you need  to remove the for loop

```
public int Blanks(int l) {
    if (l==0) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

And the method with `true-false`:

```
public boolean Blanks(int l) {
    if (l==0) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

Comment: I think I am using a loop here incorrectly... sorry for that. Still new to coding and all that. I know my method is very rough.. its practically brute force... so my next question.. not sure if I can do this.. but... is there a much more tactful way to code something that checks 1-4 to see if it is true or false?

Comment: @DarixGoof can you be more explicit? when will be true and when false? And what exactly you need to return?

Comment: basically, I am taking a 3x3 array and checking to see if a "Lane" has either something in it or not

a lane is Row # + Col #...

So [2][2] is Lane 4, [2][1].[1][2] is Lane 3, [2][0].[1][1].[0][2] is Lane 2, [1][0].[0][1] is Lane 1, and [0][0] is Lane 0

If there is something in any of the coordinates for their respective Lane, then false meaning Do not add 1 to the Return.

If there is nothing in any of the coordinates for their respective Lane, then true meaning Add 1 to Return.

This is just a checks system for another code

Comment: @DarixGoof well the second method will be better here, if the lane has `0`, then you return `0`, if there is something else than `0`, you return `1`, also you can change the method to return true or false.